# remove CR/LF in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, newline

OS: Windows

Tool: Python

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVhQMbnQd8qvhZ51_91_hazBc-_7pc_9/view?usp=sharing

I have a csv file, double quoted for free text column, comma delimited, back slash for escaping. Some rows out of positions when I use Pandas/Excel to read this csv file due to CR/LF I guess.

In python, how can I remove all the cr/lf so I can read the csv file properly? I tried this, not working as expect.

```
with open("sampledata.csv", "r") as infile,\     
   open("outfile.csv", mode="w") as outfile:     
   f = infile.read()     
   f = f.replace("\n", " ")     
   outfile.write(f)
```

Comment: With CR/LF you would rather have all rows malfunctioned. Are you able to put sample of this file somewhere? And ideally would be if you had add your Python attempt to solve that, which can we help to fix, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously didn't correctly set the escape character. I can read your file without problems (pandas 1.2.4):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("sampledata.csv", escapechar="\\").T
```

Output:

```
                                            0                                                  1
Id                         a0o7F00000B6E3GQAV                                 a0o7F000007b31GQAQ
LastModifiedDate  2021-05-04 05:37:21.0000000                        2020-03-13 23:23:54.0000000
Description           Every student needs it.  We have created our "product" which is essenti...
Age                                        30                                                 25
```